# Display content from listbox1 in listbox2 using multiselect and column count properties in MS-Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to take a user-selection from `Listbox1` (multi-select enabled) to populate `Listbox2` (no user selection in `Listbox2`). `Listbox1` has 3 columns, and is displaying column(1). I want `Listbox2` to display column(2) from `Listbox1` user selections.

I have two tables: `Summary_Data` & `Vendor_Parts`
I have one query: `Vendor_PN_Query` that is set to use a combo box selection of `Vendor` to filter to a specific vendor's list of PN's. `(Cbo_Vendor)
Column(0)=Vendor, Column(1)=PN, Column(2)=Pgm_Name`

`Cbo_Vendor` selection saves to `Summary_Data` table field `Vendor`
`PN` selection from `Listbox1` saves to `Summary_Data` table field `PN`
I need the data from `Listbox2` to save to `Summary_Data` table field `Pgm`

`Listbox1` shows `PN` field from `Vendor_PN_Query`, based on `Cbo_Vendor` user selection. User can select single or multiple PN's from this listbox by adding the checkmarks.
`Listbox2` is supposed to show the Pgm_Name(s) that is/are associated with the selected PN(s), and then record that information back into the `Summary_Data` table under the `Pgm` field.

I cannot find any code examples that actually work for this.  When I was able to code to retrieve some data, I got a repeat of the vendor name (twice for each `PN` selected), and that was all, regardless of any column count or row source variations I used in my code.

Here is my current basic code, but his does not retrieve any data for Listbox2:

```
Private Sub Cbo_Vendor_AfterUpdate()    
    Me.Listbox1.Requery        
End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_Done_Click()

   Dim i As Integer    'Row Index

   If Listbox1.ListCount = 0 Then
       MsgBox "Please select at least one part number."
       Exit Sub
   End If

   For i = 0 To Listbox1.ListCount - 1
      If Listbox1.Selected(i) = True Then
          Listbox2.AddItem Listbox1.Selected(i)
      End If
   Next i

End Sub
```

Modified code based on http://www.iaccessworld.com/29540-2/, but I still do not retrieve any results in listbox2.

```
Private Sub Cbo_Vendor_AfterUpdate()

   Me.Listbox1.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_Done_Click()

'Transfer column 2 of selected items in listbox1 to listbox2

Dim i As Integer

  With Me.Listbox1

    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
       Me.Listbox2.AddItem (Selected.Column(2, i))
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

I am finding examples online for everything from simple code like this to having to create class modules and temporary tables.  Is it really this simple and I am missing something?

I finally have code that populates Listbox2 (although it populates in reverse order - not a huge deal).  However, now I need to auto-select all items in Listbox2 and automatically save them to my table.  The field in the table is set to value list and allows multiple values.

Here is my working code:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = Listbox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If Listbox1.Selected(i) = True Then
    Listbox2.AddItem Listbox1.Column(3, i)
  End If
Next I
```

Working Code:

```
Private Sub Cbo_Vendor_AfterUpdate()
   Me.Listbox1.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_Done_Click()

'Transfer column 3 of selected items in listbox1 to listbox2
Dim i As Integer

For i = Listbox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1    'Code works but lists programs in reverse order & does not save to table.
  If Listbox1.Selected(i) = True Then
    Listbox2.AddItem Listbox1.Column(3, i)
  End If
Next I

End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_Save_Click()
    If Me.Dirty Then
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you intersperse your problem description with images of your forms, listboxes, properties etc, everyone will be able to visualize your problem better. Reading endless text with SQL, property settings and field relationships will not result in many useful answers

Comment: I am new to this forum and cannot post pictures yet.  I have tried.

Comment: Basically, I have cbo_Vendor populated from a linked table of vendor data, and the user selects a vendor.  The query is tied to the linked table of vendor data, and the part number list box is populated with part numbers for the vendor selected in the combo box.  This list box has 3 columns - Vendor, PN, Program.  I want listbox2 to display the Program for the PN's selected in Listbox1.  In a nutshell, Listbox1 displays column(1) and I want Listbox2 to display column(2) for each row produced by the query.  Does this help?

Comment: You can insert links to pictures.Where is the code you refer to that you tried ... "code to retrieve some data" Showing code that doesn't work and describing the symptoms of "not working" is a much more effective way to present a problem

Comment: Private Sub Cbo_Vendor_AfterUpdate()

    Me.Listbox1.Requery
    
End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_Done_Click()

Dim i As Integer    'Row Index


If Listbox1.ListCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please select at least one part number."
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = 0 To Listbox1.ListCount - 1
    If Listbox1.Selected(i) = True Then
    Listbox2.AddItem Listbox1.Selected(i)
    End If
Next i
           
End Sub

Comment: It has been many years since I have attempted coding in Access.  This is all my lack of experience can recall or come up with.  Nothing shows in Listbox2 and nothing is written to my table.

Comment: better example to start with here - http://www.iaccessworld.com/29540-2/

Comment: I finally got it - see edit to original post for code.  Thanks for getting me started.

Answer (score 1):

I have code that now works to transfer selected items from Listbox1 to Listbox 2, without duplicates, and then saves to Table:

```
Private Sub Cmd_Done_Click()

'Transfer column 3 of selected items in listbox1 to listbox2
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim strBlock As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim bool As Boolean

For j = Listbox2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Listbox2.Selected(i) = False
Next j

Me.Listbox2.RowSource = ""

For i = Listbox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1

    strBlock = Me.Listbox1.Column(3, i)

    If Listbox2.ListCount = 0 And strBlock <> "" Then
        If Listbox1.Selected(i) = True Then
          Listbox2.AddItem (strBlock)
          Listbox2.Selected(0) = True
        End If
    Else
        bool = False
         For x = Listbox2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If Listbox2.ItemData(x) <> strBlock Then
               If Listbox2.ItemData(x - 1) <> strBlock Then
                  bool = False
                  If Listbox1.Selected(i) = True Then
                     Listbox2.AddItem (strBlock)
                     Listbox2.Selected(x + 1) = True
                     Exit For
                  End If
               End If
            Else
                bool = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
        End If
Next i
End Sub
```